# How should I save a visitor's post before sign up?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Visitors to my site can fill out a form, it gets stored in browser session, then gets activated as a live post when the visitor signs up and confirms his email. The problem is when the browser is closed in between signing up and confirming email, the post info is lost. I can't store the job in the database because at that point there's no user ID to link it to. What should I do?

Comment: Storing the info in browser cookies could be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a table for anonymous post and an account activation key as an ID. When user activates account find his post for the activation id, add it to post table and delete it from the tmp table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a visiter user, which is default for any user that visits the site - and you can set it as the default userid in the sql table.

alternatively you could store information in cookies with a month or so expiration so if the user visits again and signs up within a month then the posts will be linked to them.

Comment: How do I transfer the post from visitor user id to the newly activated account?

Comment: with a unique session id stored in cookies - check for the unique id on the table and then swap out the user_id values

Comment: Any solution without cookies?

Answer (score 0):

store form information and a random hash in database and then send hash link to user's email.
if user clicked on that link you can get hash and check it with database information .

Comment: Does this work with confirmation codes too? User can confirm email via link or by entering code.

Comment: link can be :yoursite/index.php?h=yourhash so you can get by $_GET['h'] and compare with database hash . also user can enter code somewhere .